# Multiples voltage on a optoisolated MCU input problem

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator

### The problem

Handle digital inputs on a MCU, the input could be 5V, 12V, 24V or an open collector.

### My solution

My approach is based on jumpers, given the fact that the inputs dont change behavior in time (if the input is 0v or 5v it will be that always and never will change to 12v or 24v or open collector), so I set the jumpers one time in my circuit to work with the desired voltage. This is the most smart way i can think to solve this.

### How it works

If the input is 0V and 12V, I set **JP2** to 1-2, **JP3** to 2-3, **JP5** to 1-2 and **JP7** to 1-2. If the signal is open collector; I set **JP2** to 2-3, **JP3** to 1-2, JP4, JP5 and JP6 dont care and **JP7** to 2-3.

[image]

This seems to me the best way to go, but I don't like the amount of jumpers in my circuit, what do you think? what will be your approach?

Comment: What's the maximum frequency of your input signals?

Comment: very slow signal, below 10Hz

Comment: What current can the sensors source / sink?

Comment: you mean the MCU inputs or the external signals?

Comment: I would change the 3 resistors to 1. Then in series a zener and parallel to the zener the LED (with a current limiting resistor). Or use a JFET (eg. BF256C) to act like a (series) current source and forget about resistors (and zener) all together.

Comment: The sensor, the thing that will be attached at the far left in the schematic, but currently not shown.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the jumpers and resistors with a simple JFET current source. That alone saves you a lot of parts.

[image]

Comment: Not entirely sure if it works with 5V, the datasheets I've found so far aren't particularly clear. But I wouldn't expect much of a problem.

Comment: The Fairchild datasheet I found doesn't even explicitly say the part is a JFET.

Comment: +1, and here's an [App Note on JFET current sources](http://www.vishay.com/docs/70596/70596.pdf).